# How to reference data from other data in Vue 3

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

I have an array [] stored as a constant in Vue 3 `setup()` method. The array is composed of X objects and is part of the responses of a form.

I want to display each object in a single dynamic page for my internal dashboard with v-for in the template as a div, so I don't have to repeat code for markup. For this I thought I could do something like this:

```vue
<template>
  <div>
    <div v-for="(item, index) of entries" :key="index">
      <dt class="text-sm font-medium text-gray-500">{{ item.label }}</dt>
      <dd class="mt-1 text-sm text-gray-900">{{ item.response }} // Comes empty in the template</dd>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { ref, onMounted } from "vue";
import { supabase } from "../utils/supabaseClient.js";

export default {
  setup() {
    const data = ref({
      // It's an empty object, (all of them are strings) data is populated onMounted but it comes undefined, I also tried in beforeEnterRoute with no success
      name: "John Example",
      company: "Example Company",
      radio: "False",
    });

    const entries = ref([
      // ... more entries before this one
      {
        label: "Name",
        response: data.value.name, // this one comes undefined, as all the others I could put here.
      },
      {
        label: "Name of the company",
        response: data.value.company, // this one comes undefined, as all the others I could put here.
      },
      {
        label: "Do you have something to add?",
        response: data.value.radio, // this one comes undefined, as all the others I could put here.
      },
    ]);

    onMounted(async () => {
      //api call made with supabase client because I'm using their service.
      let { data: rows, error } = await supabase.from("submissions").select("*").order("date_submitted", { ascending: false });

      if (error) {
        console.log(error);
        return;
      }

      data.value = rows;
    });

    return {
      data,
      entries,
    };
  },
};
</script>
```

I would also like to point out that I already tried using beforeRouteEnter and onBeforeMounted, with no success.

Comment: *here I reduced it for readability purposes* - please, don't. This reduces the value of the question, you could omit some important details, and you likely did. Better reduce details that don't affect the result to provide minimal complete reproducible example, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . There's no existent problem in Vue that you describe. It doesn't matter if you use `response: data.value.radio` or `response: false` because in the code you posted `data.value.radio === false` in the scope of setup function. `v-for` syntax is ok as well.

Comment: My bad, the `data` object only contains strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`entries` should be a [`computed` prop](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/computed-watch-api.html#computed) based on `data` for it to be reactive to `data`'s changes:

```js
import { computed } from 'vue'

export default {
  setup() {
    //...

    const entries = computed(() => [
      {
        label: "Name",
        response: data.value.name,
      },
      {
        label: "Name of the company",
        response: data.value.company,
      },
      {
        label: "Do you have something to add?",
        response: data.value.radio,
      },
    ]);

    //...
  }
}
```

[demo](https://codepen.io/tony19/pen/eYvryYQ)